# Convert following data to JSON format in python

Tags: python

I have a file with following content which is generated by some other program. Please note that each one has a new line character at the end.

```
{'a':1,'b':534}
{'a':4,'b':882}
{'a':2,'b':964}
.
.
so on...
```

How do I convert this into valid JSON format?

The above should be printed something like this

```
{
    "Sale": [
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 534
        },
        {
            "a": 4,
            "b": 882
        },
        {
            "a": 2,
            "b": 964
        }
    ]
}
```

I can do it in JQuery but I need to do this in python as i am not good at python but i need to make it runnable through bash script hence the need to make it to a python script.

I am gonna share the jquery solution just in case you need to refer.

```
result = replaceAll(result,"'","\"");
result = replaceAll(result,"}, {",",");
result = replaceAll(result,"}{","},{"); 
result = replaceAll(result,"}\n{","},{");
result = "{\"Sale\":["+result+"]}";
//alert(result);
```

replaceAll function is

```
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
 var i = str.indexOf(find);
 if (i > -1){
   str = str.replace(find, replace); 
   i = i + replace.length;
   var st2 = str.substring(i);
   if(st2.indexOf(find) > -1){
     str = str.substring(0,i) + replaceAll(st2, find, replace);
   }       
 }
 return str;
}
```

The above works but i need a python alternative to this.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)? You could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the objects from the file.

Comment: The original output (which is to be converted to json) is by some other program written in C. Is there a way? Or else i will just have to dig into the source code of original program and modify that. I keeping that as a last resort.

Comment: Yes, of course there's a way, but it would be much easier if the original program output valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('data.txt') as f:
    sale = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]
    data = {'Sale': sale}
    print(data)
```

Output

```
{'Sale': [{'a': 1, 'b': 534}, {'a': 4, 'b': 882}, {'a': 2, 'b': 964}]}
```

From there, you can use the [`json` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to write this to file in JSON format.

```
import json
json.dumps(data, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from ast import literal_eval
import json
sale = []
with open(filepath) as f:
    lines = f.read()
    for line in lines:
       sale.append(literal_eval(line))
json.dumps({"sale":sale}, indent=4)
```